# Why using dup(1) before close(1), open("/dev/stdout", O_WRONLY) results in "No such file"?

Tags: c, linux, io

Problem is same as the title, the OS is linux.
I've tried a few examples.

```
dup(1);
close(1);
int fd = open("/dev/stdout", O_WRONLY);
```

This caused a "/dev/stdout No such file" error.

I thought a file descriptors is just a index to a pointer array that points to a **struct file**, and close() would clear the resources if no fd is referencing that **struct file**.
If I use dup(1), shouldn't it create a fd 3 pointing to what fd 1 was pointing, so that close(1) doesn't clear /dev/stdout?

Then I tried

```
int tmp = dup(1);
close(1);
dup(tmp, 1);
int fd = open("/dev/stdout", O_WRONLY);
```

And this worked.

I'm think I'm missing some core concepts. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This `dup(tmp, 1);` doesn't compile. Do you mean `dup2` ?

Comment: `/dev/stdout` *is* FD 1. Opening it is equivalent to duplicating fd 1. You can't close fd 1 and expect it to do anything.

Comment: `/dev/stdout` is nothing else than just a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/1`, which disappears as soon as you call `close(1)`, hence `No such file`. Calling `dup(1)` creates file descriptor 3 and `/proc/self/fd/3` file, but this obviously does not resurrect file descriptor 1 and `/proc/self/fd/1`.

Answer (score 2):

You closed stdout and then attempted to open it. But you had already closed it, so there was nothing to open. If you have no stdout, because you've closed it, then `/dev/stdout` doesn't exist.

I'm curious what you expected this to return.